# Can anybody rephrase this for me, please?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The Bank of Thailand recognizes the problem. It has held interest rates at near record lows for 16 months **despite expectations for low inflation and weak domestic and global demand, wanting more to be done on fiscal policy and structural reform.**

source: http://www.cnbc.com/2016/08/11/asia-loses-its-policy-punch-as-consumers-pile-on-debt.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it has held interest rates at near record lows for 16 months

The Bank has not made a recent change to interest rates, the rates are very low,

> despite expectations for low inflation and weak domestic and global demand,

even though there are conditions that might lead us to expect a further lowering of rates

> wanting more to be done on fiscal policy and structural reform.

the Bank feels that the government should address "low inflation and weak domestic and global demand" by modifying its fiscal policy and implementing some structural reforms.